# What do the perf record choices of LBR vs DWARF vs fp do?

Tags: linux, perf

When I use the `perf record` on my code, I find three choices for the `--call-graph` option: `lbr` (last branch record), `dwarf` and `fp`.

What is difference between these?

Comment: @Zulan: heh, I was wondering what "pf" was.  Didn't think of it being a typo for "frame pointer", but now this makes sense for stack-unwinding.

Comment: I believe this question is on-topic: It is about the usage of `perf`, an established tool for which we have a dedicated tag. While this particular topic is somewhat covered in the documentation, I believe this question and the answer add more value.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/680996/

Answer (score 18):

The option `--call-graph` refers to the collection of call graphs / call chains, i.e. the function stack for a sample.

The default, `fp`, uses *frame pointers*. This is very efficient but can be unreliable, particularly for optimized code. By explicitly using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, you can ensure that this is available for *your* code. Nevertheless, the result for libraries may vary.

With `dwarf`, `perf` actually collects and stores a part of the stack memory itself and unwinds it with post-processing. This can be very resource consuming and may have limited stack depth. The default stack memory chunk is 8 kiB, but can be configured.

`lbr` stands for *last branch records*. This is a hardware mechanism support by Intel CPUs. This will probably offer the best performance at the cost of portability. `lbr` is also limited to userspace functions.

Comment: LBR is not really recent, it's been there since the P6.

Comment: After digging deeper, it turns out that the LBR call stack support requires particular LBR feature (bit 9 of `MSR_LBR_SELECT`), which is only available starting with Haswell. If the user specified to `perf record` profile *only* kernel callchains, then the tool will fall back to `fp` mode. Also, if branch sampling is enabled, `perf record` will fall back to `fp` mode because both features use the same LBR registers, so that they cannot be used together. When `perf record` falls back, a warning is printed to the user.

Comment: See the [code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a9815a4fa2fd297cab9fa7a12161b16657290293/tools/perf/util/evsel.c#L693). Although I'm not sure what happens when running on a processor that doesn't support bit 9 of `MSR_LBR_SELECT`. Maybe it will also fall back to `fp`, but I didn't find this check in the code.

Comment: when I use "--call-graph dwarf",I found that some of the function information was printed incorrectly(the position of the function on the flame graph is not quite correct.), and I suspect it was a thread problem, so I would like to ask what attention should be paid to using perf to track and print multithreaded information.

Comment: I don't know any general issues in that direction. This is best addressed in an additional question, but make sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Theflash I am seeing this problem now, same capture dwarf vs lbr produces incorrect flamegraph in dwarf case. Have you got any further findings in your case?